# What do the file names in large git repositories mean?

Tags: git, github

I notice almost all big repositories on Github have the same file names in their root directories, such as src, and so on.

What do these common 2-3 letter names mean?

Comment: src means "source", hmm its a shortcut for words like "bin" means binaries, "dist" means distribution and etc

Answer (score 2):

The file names have nothing to do with git. They are just the normal organizations or structures of codes and projects. As Mahan's comments, src means "source" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Since git project contains code there are few conventions for renaming code folders.

If its a web project for example you will find folder like:

```
 js     // JavaScript
 src    // can be any src (php, java etc)
 css    // folder for stylesheets

... and so on.
```

Its simply a short name for folders.

Here is an example of project skeleton:

[image]